Asphalt Driveway Repair
A contractor dumped a large load of gravel on my driveway by mistake (it was supposed to be at the new construction site 1 block over). They cleaned it up, but now it is scratched up everywhere including some scratches that are 1/4" deep. Aside from seal coating it, what can be done? I'm hoping to go back to them with a repair estimate.
Photos: https://1drv.ms/f/s!Ag44uXvtqhfqhJw6WT-rvhlpvf1y1w?e=3b5ylh

Do not think 1/4 inch is deep enough for asphalt repair, too deep for simple sealing to cover(unless multiple coats over scratches).  Coat, let dry, recoat.

crack-repair in the scratches, followed by sealcoat. but call a professional.

Get your professional repair estimate.  They are the best source of answers for this.

TBH, you have cracks way worse than the chips.  It doesn't look like much to me.  maybe I am looking at the wrong bit.

Well, the contractor will need to pay to reseal, so get some quotes as @Jasen suggests.  You might as well get an add-on quote for crack repair, but the contractor won't pay for that.
